# angularjs dataTables format number with spaces

Tags: angularjs, datatables, format, firebase-realtime-database, number-formatting

I have get my number field value from firebase and inject into the table like this:

```
<td><label>{{obj.mynumber}}</label></td>
```

mynumber values are like this:

```
10 000
2 000
10
250 000 000
```

when I sort the column, it sorts it based on the digits until the first space, which is wrong.
So i need to reformat it as a number and remove the spaces.
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a dedicated filter :

```
angular.module('filters.stringUtils', [])

.filter('removeSpaces', [function() {
    return function(string) {
        if (!angular.isString(string)) {
            return string;
        }
        return string.replace(/[\s]/g, '');
    };
}])
```

and call it like :

```
<td><label>{{obj.mynumber.toString() | removeSpaces}}</label></td>
```

Comment: I get this error: `Error: $parse:syntax
Syntax Error`

Comment: How to add a dollar sign to the end of it as well? thanks

Comment: Just concate it like {{(obj.mynumber.toString() | removeSpaces) + '$'}}